# React-hook-form fields flash empty before populating with default values in Next.js

Tags: next.js, react-hook-form

I'm trying to determine if I'm implementing everything correctly. I'm using Next.js 13.4 with the app router and processing some form data using react-hook-form. Everything seems to be working fine, except for one potential issue. When I set default values, the form input fields are initially empty and only get populated after JavaScript loads, resulting in a sort of flashing effect.

This is simplified client side form component:

```
"use client"

import { UserType } from '@/types/UserType'
import * as Checkbox from '@radix-ui/react-checkbox'
import { CheckIcon } from '@radix-ui/react-icons'
import Link from "next/link"
import React from "react"
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form"

type Inputs = {...}

export default function ProfileForm({ data }: { data: UserType}) {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setError,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm<Inputs>({ defaultValues: data })

return (
...
    <input
      {...register("name")}
      name="name"
      type="text"
      className="bg-transparent border-b border-purple-2" />
      <p className="text-xs text-red-600 mt-1 h-4">
        {errors.name && errors.name.message}
      </p>
...
)
```

And this is how I'm sending initial data to above component, again simplifield:

```
import { authOptions } from "@/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route";
import AppHeader from "@/app/components/AppHeader";
import ProfileForm from "@/app/components/forms/profile";
import { SessionType } from "@/types/SessionType";
import { UserType } from "@/types/UserType";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";

async function getProfile() {
  const res = await fetch(`...`, {
    ...
  })

  return res.json()
}

export default async function Update() {
  const data: UserType = await getProfile()

  return (
    <>
      ...
      <div className="pt-32">
        <ProfileForm data={data} />
      </div>
      ...
    </>
  )
}
```